Particles disappear when trying to convert to mesh/curve/etc
I've made a sunflower using particle system and i can't convert the particicle system to mesh or curve or etc, particles just dissapear.
I tried to do it with coding, tried to fix some settings, tried like 8 different ways of how i can fix it, nothing worked. from simple ones as installing older and more stable versions of Blender (3.6 LTS) to exporting to another format and importing, tried baking, tried literally EVERYTHING, particles just dissapear when converting. i always have two meshes after converting so as it should be, one - original, - has particicle system, and one another that should be full mesh just doesn't have that part with hair.
I tried to do it with modifiers, nothing works.
Maybe someone knows what can it be? maybe i need to fix something with my Blender.

Can you show some images of your scene and your modifier stack/settings so we can get an idea of the problem? That or can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

hey! no modifiers except particle, yes i can send the project
